# Determining the pattern in a basic numerical series

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, pattern-recognition

In the context of finding the series solution for a variable coefficient ODE, I have to determine if a consistent pattern exists between the following numbers:

$\frac{-1} {3!},\frac{-1} {5!},\frac{-3} {7!}, \frac{-15} {9!}\frac{-105} {11!}$

I really cant spot it... any hints?

EDIT

it looks like Im looking for a function of the type "odd number factorial"
Since:

$-1*1=-1$

$-1*3=-3$

$-3*5=-15$

$-3*5*7=-105$

However I have no idea how to generate this....

Comment: Do You know how to generate even factorial? Hint : use powers of 2. And factorials.

Comment: on wikipedia it says n!! but for example if I take 4!! I get (4*3*2*1)=24 Then 24*23*22*21....1 >> 4*2.... So i think I am not understanding double factorial very well

Comment: anyone can give some insight?

Comment: Even factorials. As in 2*4*6*8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, the numerators correspond to double factorial of odd numbers and the denominators to factorial of odd numbers.

So the general term of your numbers seems to be $$-\frac{(2 n-3)\text{!!}}{(2 n+1)!}$$

Comment: You did the work, not me ! What you wrote after *Edit* in the post gave me the trick. Cheers :-)

Comment: Indeed it is. That was quite amazing. Thanks.